# QGIS bookmarks and map extent

Tags: qgis, extents, bookmarks

I have  set a bookmark within QGIS and would like to set another bookmark just slightly east of the current one but with the same scale and north-south extent. If I use the pan tool the north-south extent changes because I can't hold my hand that still. I don't see scroll bars in the window and the arrows on the keyboad go too far to the east. Is there any other way I can shift the window slightly to the east without changing the latitude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance by which the canvas is moved with the arrow keys depends on the current width/height.

If you first zoom into the scene (Page Up or scale combobox) you can pan with the arrow keys in smaller steps. Finally zoom out again (Page Down or scale combobox) to revert to the original scale.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pan tool to move the extent, save the bookmark and than rewrite yMin and yMax values to required north-south extent.

Example:
[image]

Note: This is handy only if you have a few bookmarks. If you need a lots of them it will be better export a .xlm bookmark file, do some find and replace for yMin and yMax and import .xml file back.